# Why background image is not getting responsive according to screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used twitter bootstrap to make a webpage.
I have inserted an image in background through CSS as following.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <section id="wrapper">

        </section>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS is as follows:

```
section#wrapper{ 
    max-width:700px; 
    background-image:url("img/crane.png");
    min-height:525px;
}
```

When I resize browser size the image is not getting resized according to screen size.
I am not getting how to make it responsive.
So please can any one help me out to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up `background-size` (doesn't work in older browsers, though)

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
section#wrapper{ 
    background:url("img/crane.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `background-size` property and set it to `cover` like in the following shorthand:

```
div.withBackground {
    background:  url('http://image.url/img.png') center center cover;
}
```

read more [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3 `background-size` with `cover` as a value and not `100%` property for a full page responsive background image for your website

```
html { 
  background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[For more info](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 1):

try this `background-size:100%;`

but not all browser works lower version of browser not recognize `background-size`

Comment: it is working when I made the change.. but I have written min-height:525px; when I change this property to height:525px or max-height:525px then image is disappearing.

Comment: hi do you have [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your current progress? so i can see the problem.